# Kernel of a module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and let $R=F[x,y,z]$. Let $M=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $x,y,z$. Define an $R$-module homomorphism $$\phi:R^3\to M,\quad (f_1,f_2,f_3)\mapsto xf_1+yf_2+zf_3.$$
I want to show that $\ker \phi=\langle (0,z,-y),(-z,0,x),(y,-x,0)\rangle$. It is clear that the right side is contained in $\ker \phi$, but how to show the opposite?

Comment: Suppose $(f,g,h)\in ker(\phi)$ so that $xf+yg+zh=0$. Then $h(-z,0,x)-g(y,-x,0)=(-yg-zh,xg,xh)=(xf,xg,xh)$. This is almost what you want, maybe try playing around with other $R$-linear combinations?

Comment: @ngenisis Could you say it more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xf_1+yf_2+zf_3=0\implies xf_1\in(y,z)\implies f_1\in(y,z)\implies f_1=yg_1+zh_1$, so $y(xg_1+f_2)+z(xh_1+f_3)=0\implies xg_1+f_2=zf, xh_1+f_3=-yf$. Then $(f_1,f_2,f_3)=(y,-x,0)g_1+(-z,0,x)(-h_1)+(0,z,-y)f$.